# mock cake request to stub out the data function

Tags: cakephp, mocking, phpunit

I have been searching all around the internet on how to mock cake requests. i want to stub out the data function to make $this->request->data('whatever') available in the controller. but something is going wrong with my test case

```php
$Jobs = $this->generate('Tasks' , array(
  'components' => array(        
    'RequestHandler' => array('isMobile','prefers','renderAs'))
));
// Mock CakeRequest
$request = $this->getMock('CakeRequest', array('_readInput'));      
$Jobs->RequestHandler->request = $request;

$Jobs->RequestHandler->request->expects($this->any())
  ->method('data')->with('anything')->will($this->returnValue('test'));

$result = $this->testAction('/tasks/test/',
            array('method' => 'get', 'return' => 'vars'));
```

whenever i call `$this->request->data('anything')` in the controller it returns null!

Please try to help me with this

Answer (score 0):

From the PhpUnit documentation :

> By default, all methods of the given class are replaced with a test double that just returns NULL unless a return value is configured using will($this->returnValue()), for instance.
>
> When the second (optional) parameter is provided, only the methods whose names are in the array are replaced with a configurable test double. The behavior of the other methods is not changed.

So you need to either do this :

```
$Jobs = $this->generate('Tasks' , array(
    'components' => array(        
    'RequestHandler' => array('isMobile','prefers','renderAs'))
));
// Mock CakeRequest
$request = $this->getMock('CakeRequest', array('_readInput'));      
$Jobs->RequestHandler->request = $request;

$Jobs->RequestHandler->request->expects($this->any())
    ->method('_readInput')->with('anything')->will($this->returnValue('test'));

$result = $this->testAction('/tasks/test/',
        array('method' => 'get', 'return' => 'vars'));
```

or this :

```
$Jobs = $this->generate('Tasks' , array(
    'components' => array(        
    'RequestHandler' => array('isMobile','prefers','renderAs'))
));
// Mock CakeRequest
$request = $this->getMock('CakeRequest', array('data'));      
$Jobs->RequestHandler->request = $request;

$Jobs->RequestHandler->request->expects($this->any())
    ->method('data')->with('anything')->will($this->returnValue('test'));

$result = $this->testAction('/tasks/test/',
        array('method' => 'get', 'return' => 'vars'));
```

As I don't know cakePHP I can't tell you which is the right answer.
But according to this : http://api20.cakephp.org/view_source/controller-test-dispatcher
(line 232), you should try the former one.